# How can i Get the paramter of URL contains slash

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, php-5.5

I have this URL :

```
 dev.local.co/fr/admin/quoteManag/addquote/numberModel/123456/5
```

when I want to get the parameter `numberModel`.

On `var_dump` I get just "123456", not "123456/5"

Comment: It would be useful if you could edit your question to include the code you are currently using to get the URL parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

```
$parameter = urlencode('123456/5'); // 123456%2F5

echo urldecode($_GET['numberModel']); // 123456/5
```

Or in your router, create a regex that will accept the slash as part of the parameter.

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex("numberModel/([0-9\/]*)", array("module" => "MODULE", "controller" => "CONTROLLER", "action" => "ACTION"), array(1 => "numberModel"));
```

Comment: @Tim Fountain :      So i disply the parameter String on URL
123456/5
when i var_dumped i get just
this 12345
so why i am not Get The All String of Paramter thanks also

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% but if this was me, I would get the url, explode it using /
Get the last 2 from the array, implode them.

But it depends on how you get the url, do you have a rewrite rule?
If so then I would look in that and you need to just sharpen it up slightly.